# How to make a perfect circle

Tags: html, css

I don't know what other technique i can use to make a perfect circle. The problem tells me that the circle must have 200px of diameter on CSS. Yet, someone made it differently using other variables. I want to do it the right way but don't know how.

I'd created a div which specifies the image to have 200px but still it didn't work

```
<img class="rounded" src="https://assets.breatheco.de/apis/img/funny/einstein.png" />
```

Comment: [Read about `border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

Answer (score 1):

Use `border-radius` to achieve the circle.
[Read more about border radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

```css
.circle {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #d8d8d8;
border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `boder-radius: 50%;` to the image:

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
```